# How to write a query for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, support, scope, site-recommendation

I'd like to write a query in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer for the Cross Validated site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/queries), which returns me the Question and Answers on Cross Validated by month and by tag, for the 10 tags which today have the most unanswered questions. If this isn't possible, it's OK to select the 10 tags which have the most questions, such as the most popular tags.

Thus, it'd be a modification of "[Questions and Answers per Month](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/869988/questions-and-answers-per-month#graph)", where the grouping is not only done by month, but by tag too.

The problem is, I don't know SQL. Would this question be on topic on SO or should I ask it on Meta SE? SQL is a programming language, so I think it would be on topic on SO, but I've seen questions about the SE Data Explorer being asked on Meta SE.

Comment: MSE has a tag for it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer and there are plenty of *write this query for me* which are received well if they include some sort of an attempt. I would only ask on SO if you have a specific problem in T-SQL that you can't solve on your own. I would have high hopes for a rewrite this query question on SO.

Comment: If you say *by month and by tag, for the 10 tags...* do you mean that you want those 10 tags represented in one query / graph, with 2 data columns per tag, so 20 in total, and a date?

Comment: ok, then I'll ask on MSE. I cannot show much effort - I have only the faintest idea of what SQL is (what's T-SQL? I thought the query was in SQL). "I would have high hopes for a rewrite this query question on SO" - I guess it's a typo. You meant "I wouldn't have high hopes for a rewrite this query question on SO", right?

Comment: @rene yes, exactly. 21 columns (two per tags + a date column).

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is a typo  *I would **NOT** have high hopes for a "rewrite this query" question on SO*

Comment: @DeltaIV T-SQL is Microsoft's implementation of SQL.  Generally if you actually want to ask an SQL question on SO, you are usually going to want to indicate which DBMS you are using because that will change the features you have access too.  And the actual query will vary from DBMS to DBMS because of variations in variation vendors.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization

Comment: @psubsee2003 Since the database system used by StackExchange is SQL Server, which uses T-SQL - Microsoft's dialect of SQL -- you use T-SQL for queries in the Data Explorer.

Comment: Stackoverflow will probably downvote you however you might ask them, ask on other one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need a lot of help, none of the Stack Exchange sites are a great venue. The Q/A model doesn't lend itself for one-on-one tutoring.

That rules out you can ask on Stack Overflow without running the risk of having your question closed as too broad or off-topic/no mcve. Only when you run into a specific problem with the T-SQL statements (Microsoft's implementation of SQL) you could turn to SO proper. I've done that once for a SEDE related problem.

For the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://stackexchange.com/) there is a pretty active group of users on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) that take questions and query request although they prefer that you have shown an attempt (try the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)!), did some research etc. Also important is to formulate clear requirements. I don't like to go back and forth after I delivered a first version.

Your best chance of getting an answer with a working query is by asking on MSE. I would **NOT** have high hopes for a *rewrite this query* question when posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I asked on MSE, as you suggest.

Answer (score 7):

Dare I suggest this, but the SO chatroom's can be a great place for extended discussion and for lots of input on larger problems, a few of the chatroom's regularly get together over a single problem and try to figure out answers. Might be worth dropping into one of the rooms to do with SQL and seeing if someone there wants to help out.

Comment: Chat is definitely a good option, specially if the OP is in the research phase and/or if it's unclear if SEDE has the data needed to fulfill their requirement.

Comment: Turns out there is now a [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) on MSE chat and a [SEDE room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13526/sede-stack-exchange-data-explorer) on SE chat.